# Getting error while rendering form in active admin dashboard - rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am getting error while rendering   the form from partial   in  active admin dashboard.My form partial look like:

**app/views/admin/dashboard/_form.html.arb**

```
insert_tag active_admin_form_for :bill do |f|
  inputs do
  input :from_date
  input :to_date
  input :expiry_date
  end
  actions
end
```

And my dashboard code looks like :

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do

 columns do
   column do
     panel "Generate Bills" do

        render partial: 'form'  #rendering form partial

     end
   end
  end
end
```

I am getting following error while clicking on dashboard menu link :

[image: Error pic]
help me out 
thnxx!

Comment: see that last pic in red color !

Comment: Did you add bill to active_admin resource?

Comment: ofcourse... I have .. the problem is , I am not able to create objects from dashboard of active admin.I want just simple form in dashboard which creates bill attributes!

Comment: Hey! Greetings from 2020 )))
It seems you have problem in your `_form` partial. Could you share it?

Comment: I think I solved that lol It was 3 years ago